# Accessing coordinates of a marker created in Mapbox GL using pg_featureserv

Tags: jquery, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am utilizing Mapbox GL and pg_featureserv, and I need assistance with accessing the coordinates of a created marker. I want to print these coordinates in the console but I am unsure of the method to access them. Can someone provide guidance on how to access the result, possibly using a specific command?

```
map.on('load', function() { 
   var myLayer = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
         {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': []}
            }
        ]
    };        
map.addSource('myLayer', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": myLayer
        });
                
map.loadImage('marker.png', function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;
        map.addImage('marker', image);
            
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'points',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'myLayer',
        'minzoom' : 15,
        'layout': {
        'icon-image': 'marker',
        'icon-size': 1,
        'icon-allow-overlap': true
        },
        "filter": ["all",["==","$type","Point"]]
             });
    });
    /* Search functionality using pg_featureserv */   
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
            
            var url = "http://localhost:9000/functions/postgisftw.search/items.json?searchstr=";
            var q = encodeURI(request.term);
            var t = `&centerlng=${centerlng}&centerlat=${centerlat}`;
            $.get(url+q+t, function(data) {
                response(data.features.map(function(d) {
                  return {
                    "value": d["properties"]["name"],
                    "address": d["properties"]["address"],
                    "geometry": d["geometry"]
                  }
                }));
            });               
        },
        minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {       
        myLayer.features = [ui.item];
        var bounds = turf.bbox(ui.item.geometry);
        map.fitBounds(bounds,{padding: {top: 100, bottom:100, left: 100, right: 100}});
        map.getSource('myLayer').setData(myLayer);
    }       
})
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var t = String(item.value).replace(
                    new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                    "<strong>$&</strong>");
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                    .append("<div><b>" + t + "</b><br>" + item.address + "</div>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
            
});
var features = map.getSource('myLayer').setData(myLayer)._options.data.features[0];
console.log(features);
```

I tried to use (.setData(myLayer)._options.data), but failed

var features = map.getSource('myLayer').setData(myLayer)._options.data.features[0];
console.log(features);